# how to reduce current without changing voltage?

Tags: current, amperage

In my car there is a  charger it is producing 5v/2amps,but there is a clock in my car, this clock is connected to this car charger it need only 5v/500ma,how can i reduce the current to this clock?

Comment: You don't need to, period.

Comment: The current is determined by the load which is less than the supply limit.

Comment: search about constant current vs constant voltage supply.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of the many questions on this site where people are not understanding Ohm's law.

The important thing to realise with your clock, and with any electronic device, they will draw the current they are designed to draw if given the voltage they are supposed to be given. Plug the clock into the 5V, 2A source, and it will draw significantly less than 500mA. All will be fine.

Comment: It's a misuderstanding of voltage sources, not of Ohm's law. Ohm's law relates voltage and current linearly to a resistive load. The clock does not need to follow a linear relation, and it probably does not. It's actually a misuderstanding of Ohm's law to state that this question is a misunderstanding of Ohm's law. I agree that this question is replicated under various forms in this site, almost every day.

Comment: +1 for the comment. These questions at least partly arise from the abbreviations for power supplies like 12V/2A. The meaning of those two figures is by convention totally different: 12V is the nominal voltage, provided that the current is below 2A. A casual electronics user doesn't know this. But then, maybe such a casual user shouldn't use electronics.